# set data-src dynamic in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, src

I am trying to set the data-src dynamic, so under certain condition, it will get data from service dataOneOne, and other time, it will get data from dataOneTwo . here is the html code

```
<div class="dataOne" data-src="dataOneOne"></div>
```

dataOneOne is a GET service that will return data, however, i want to set the data-src dynamic. so under some circumstance, it will call dataOneTwo.

Below are the code I tried in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if(some circumstance){
   $("div.dataOne").attr("data-src", "dataOneTwo");
   var data = document.getElementByClass("dataOne");
   console.log(data); // the console log shows <div class="dataOne" data-src="dataOneTwo"></div>, but in network, it's still calling the dataOneOne GET service 
   // also tried below option too, 
   $("div.dataOne").data("src", "dataOneTwo"); // both console log and network are showing or using dataOneOne
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.data` both to read and set the data attribute. In particular, do not mix `.attr` with `.data`, as setting a value with `.data` does not set the HTML attribute.

```js
const src = $("div.dataOne").data('src'); // get value
$("div.dataOne").data('src', 'dataOneTwo'); // set value
```